Is the abelianization of a p-torsion free ring also p-torsion free?
Definiton: For a ring $R$, define the commutator of $R$ to be $\langle R, R \rangle $, the ideal generated by $\{xy-yx: x, y \in R\}$. Then the abelianization of $R$ is defined to be the quotient ring $R/\langle R, R \rangle$, denoted by $R^{ab}$.
My question: For a prime number $p$, if $R$ is $p$-torsion free as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module then is $R^{ab}$ also $p$-torsion free?
I think there is a counterexample to it, but I cannot find it.

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}1 \oplus \mathbb{Z}a \oplus \mathbb{Z}b$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, which is torsion free. Define multiplication on $R$ via the following multiplication table:
$$\begin{matrix}
xy & y=1 & y=a & y=b\\
x=1 & 1 & a & b\\
x=a & a & 0 & 0\\
x=b & b & pa & pb
\end{matrix}$$
One may check that the multiplication, thus defined, is indeed associative. By a direct calculation, the commutator ideal is,
$$\langle R, R \rangle = p\mathbb{Z}a$$
So, the abelianization, as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, is $\mathbb{Z}1 \oplus (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})a \oplus \mathbb{Z}b$, which is, of course, no longer $p$-torsion free.

Great answer. Can you please share how you found that ring? It makes sense in retrospective, though.

@MartinBrandenburg It’s just the result of playing around. To get what OP needed, there has to be two non-commuting generators $a$ and $b$. Then we need a unity. And the easiest way to get the quotient to be not $p$-torsion free seems to be making the commutator of $a$ and $b$ to be $p$ times one of the generators, and the easiest way to do that seems to be setting multiplication in one direction to be $0$ and the other to be $pa$ or $pb$. Then it’s just the result of trying a few things until you get an associative multiplication.
